# How to detect a collision using UICollisionBehavior in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, collision

I'm having problems detecting when an object collides another object. I'm trying to not use SpriteKit, I have used UICollisionBeahvior but I don't know how to use it properly.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks! :)

```
func checkEdgesTouched() -> Bool{

    detectRightCollision = UICollisionBehavior(items: [rightSide])
    detectLeftCollision = UICollisionBehavior(items: [leftSide])
    collisionPlayer = UICollisionBehavior(items: [player])

    if detectLeftCollision != nil{
        Setscore()
        return true
    } else if detectRightCollision != nil {
        Setscore()
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

Comment: What is the disadvantage of using SpriteKit?

Comment: No disadvantage but i'm trying to not use it